# hibernate session is null with hibernate-envers

Tags: apache-karaf, hibernate-envers, blueprint-osgi

I am facing a serious problem with hibernate-Enver(auditing). My hibernate-5.0.0-final was working perfactly fine. Now I need to add auditing feature to my entities , so I added the `@Audited` annotation to my entities. When I deployed it on karaf OSGI. i am getting `hibernate session null` with the exception :

```
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversService]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.TypeContributorImpl.contribute(TypeContributorImpl.java:22)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.applyTypes(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.populate(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:798)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiPersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(OsgiPersistenceProvider.java:78)
```

I install feature of Hibernate Enver also :

```
feature:install hibernate-orm
feature:install hibernate-envers
```

I am stuck with it.. Can anyOne help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Issue Resoved when Update the Hibernate from `Hibernate-5.0.0.Final to Hibernate-5.2.0`
helping link: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10365